# If i pay 0.001 to cloud mining site such az minezone.io or bitbase.club or 99quick.cloud

Tags: transactions

If i pay 0.001 to cloud mining site such az minezone.io or bitbase.club or 99quick.cloud, they give my balance or no

Comment: Pretty much all cloud mining is a scam

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't trust them at all.

Take minezone.io for example, they claim to be a London-based company. The company number they have on their ["FAQ" page](https://minezone.io/faq.php) is for BITEXPLOSION LIMITED whose [registration status](https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/10757099) is "Active — Active proposal to strike off". Being struck off is a bad thing. Their annual confirmation statement is four months overdue. That also is a bad sign.

Bitbase.club's website is an almost exact copy and also gives the same company number (i.e. BITEXPLOSION LIMITED)

The 99Click.cloud domain doesn't seem to exist.